# rtab map mapcloud/mapData working but cloud_map is empty!

Tags: ros, rtabmap, vslam

I'm trying to retrieve the pointclouds built from rtab map, im using gz garden with ros1 bridge to get my input topics. my launch file is :

roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch depth_topic:=/slam/depth_image rgb_topic:=/slam/image camera_info_topic:=/slam/camera_info rtabmapviz:=true mapping:=true frame_id:=bluerov2/base_link/rgbd_camera

i can see the mapped pointcloud fine in rtabviz and in rviz i can see the mapped data under mapcloud/MapData plugin, but cloud_map topic is empty.

how can i get it to work/ use the map cloud to use the realtime pointcloud points

EDIT1: ive also checked that the depth map is of standard format R_FLOAT32

EDIT2:
update: i was able to use mapAssembler node for this issue but that still doesnt explain why the topic under /rtabmap/cloud_map is empty? @matlabbe